# Error al cargar una imagen en un jlabel

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen gif en mi aplicación que muestre un cargando estilo windows, el problema es que siempre no importa como sea la imagen siempre me tira un `NullPointerException`, si paso la imagen por propiedad me lo genera, si la paso por codigo me lo genera, alguien podria ayudar a como sulucionar esto??

Asi es como lo estoy tratando:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("301.gif"));
lblIcon.setIcon(icon);
```

Y por propiedad asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PEro aun asi me sigue generando este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at edu.cecar.vista.FrmVistaPrincipal.initComponents(FrmVistaPrincipal.java:124)
at edu.cecar.vista.FrmVistaPrincipal.<init>(FrmVistaPrincipal.java:23)
at edu.cecar.main.PrincipalMain$1.run(PrincipalMain.java:57)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

No entiendo por que me genera siempre el mismo error, si utilizo un metodo o el otro apunta a una linia en especifico y es donde se carga la imagen, estoy utilizando un proyecto con estructura maven, lo cual no creo que me tenga que generar algún tipo de conflicto.

Comment: Depende del paquete y la ubicación del gif.

Comment: se encuentra en la misma ruta de la interfaz

Comment: Con la ruta absoluta ¿obtienes el recurso?

Comment: error de igual forma

Comment: Donde quedan las clases compiladas ¿hay una copia del gif?

Comment: No no hay una copia del gif

Comment: Selecciona `Build project`, si no se copia el gif prueba copiándolo manualmente.

Comment: siii funciono copiando directo en la carpeta de compilados

Comment: Pregunta duplicada: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente hay que:

1. Verificar que el recurso se incluya.

   En Netbeans, en *Project Properties > Sources > Includes/Excludes* el archivo de la imagen debe estar en `Included Files`, de lo contrario habrá que agregar el folder y/o modificar la expresión `Includes` para incluir el archivo de la imagen.
2. Construir nuevamente el proyecto.

   En Netbeans seleccionar *Run > Clean and Build Project*.

Hecho lo anterior deberá haber una copia del archivo de la imagen en `build/classes/ruta/del/paquete/`, si por alguna razón no existiera, basta con hacer una copia manual del archivo.